# First questions queue is not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

First questions queue is not working properly. I noticed this a couple of hours ago and it has been not fixed yet.

[image]

[image]

(Screenshots on mobile device)

Comment: I can reproduce this error (Desktop, Chrome) and the review history looks like no one else  is currently accessing the first question review queue, either.

Comment: I cant reproduce it (tried loading all 8 items in the queue) or find an error log. What url are you trying to load (ie: does it include a ReviewTaskId in the url)? Is it still happening now?

Comment: @YaakovEllis still buggy using my iPad…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero if you are able, can you please trying on a desktop, and see what you are getting in the network and console tabs in dev tools (F12) when you see this error?

Comment: @YaakovEllis see answer below.

Comment: ok, thanks. on it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed now. Please let me know if you see it again.

Comment: Thanks, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

On my MacBook Air running BigSur 11.6:

Console:

[image]

Network:

[image]